# Batch Files - getting File Summary into text file

Tags: batch-file, file-management

I've got a ZIP file of 32,000 PDF reports that I need to rename to a more descriptive name, plus generate a TXT file of all the files and their sub-folders.  I have been using the

`dir /b /s >info.txt`

command line for some years now, but obviously this just gives what the current file name is.  However, when I move the mouse over the file, I get the full title, author, etc.  When I right click on one of the files that information is in the PDF tab, not in the Summary tab.

So - my question is how can I rename these files to the title that is in the *Title* field, allowing me to scan through the list quickly and easily?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: I doubt that can be done from a plain batch file/command. If you are willing to use powershell or wscript: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/08/13/how-can-i-find-files-metadata.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure, but WMIC may be able to help?  See http://superuser.com/questions/363278/is-there-a-way-to-get-file-metadata-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks Rene / Nate - Unfortunately I have very limited users rights on my PC at work and because the information is highly confidential I can't bring it home to work on.  I was hoping to be able to do this through a Batch, but obviously it won't work.  Is there something that can be done in VBA or even VB.NET (I have 2005) that could do what I need?  Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using [PDFTK](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit)

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "pdftk=c:\Program Files\PDF Labs\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe"
set "pdfs=C:\PDFS"
set "rep=%temp%\rep.txt"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %pdfs%\*.pdf /s /b /a-d') do (
  if exist %rep% del %rep%
  "%pdftk%" "%%a" dump_data output "%rep%"
   for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=: " %%b in ('findstr /n .* %rep%') do (
      if "%%b" equ "6" echo(ren "%%a" "%%d.pdf"
   )    
  pause
 )
```

Change the file paths as appropriate to your environment. This will echo what the rename command will be to the screen. If all looks well, remove the `echo(` from in front of the ren to actually do the operation. Also, I added a `pause` in the loop because you have so many files it would fill your screen buffer in a few seconds. When you're ready to go, just remove it.